# Concat and minify using gulp conflict with node.js file

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify

I have written a script to concat and minify some java-script files in my project. When I run it using both Visual Studio 2015 and Power-shell, it gives me an error message at the end. Please see attached screen shot for the script and the error message.

According to the error message my idea is; 
The script tries to concat/minify the node.js files too, because the error is related to a node.js file, but that that cannot be happened because I have not included any reference to Node.js in the ‘Layout.cshtml’.

Someone please explain me the mistake I have done.

```js
/// <vs />
// include plug-ins
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var htmlbuild = require('gulp-htmlbuild');
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var es = require('event-stream');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var ignore = require('gulp-ignore');

// pipe a glob stream into this and receive a gulp file stream 
var gulpSrc = function (opts) {
    var paths = es.through();
    var files = es.through();
    paths.pipe(es.writeArray(function (err, srcs) {
        var fixedFiles = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < srcs.length; i++) {
            fixedFiles[i] = srcs[i].replace("~", ".");
            console.log(fixedFiles[i]);
        }
        gulp.src(fixedFiles, opts).pipe(files);
    }));
    return es.duplex(paths, files);
};

var jsBuild = es.pipeline(
    plugins.concat('all.js'),
    gulp.dest('./Scripts/')
);

gulp.task('clean', function () {
    return gulp.src('./Scripts/all.js')
            .pipe(clean({ force: true }));
});

gulp.task('build', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./Views/Home/Layout.cshtml'])
    .pipe(htmlbuild({
        js: htmlbuild.preprocess.js(function (block) {
            block.pipe(gulpSrc())
           .pipe(jsBuild);
        })
    }));
    process.stdout.write('build is done');
});

gulp.task('minify', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./Scripts/all.js']).
    pipe(uglify()).
    pipe(gulp.dest('./testing'));
});
gulp.task('default', ['clean', 'build', 'minify'], function () { });
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Posting these as images instead of text makes it very difficult for us to play with the code and experiment. Have mercy, don't make people re-type all of that by hand. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is being thrown by [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) within your `minify` task. It is telling you that the JavaScript code it is operating on could not be parsed correctly. In other words, there is a [SyntaxError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError) in the file `Scripts/all.js`.

It is unfortunate that Uglify gives such a low-quality error for this. I suggest you take that file and run it through a linter like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). It will do a good job at showing you where exactly the `SyntaxError` is within the file. This is an important step in your toolchain and should be done as early as possible (on the module level, rather than on built code).